# Синонимы метки [юнит-тесты], [test] и [testing]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

На текущий момент следующие метки заменяются на [юнит-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b):

[unit-testing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing), [unittest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unittest), [модульные-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b), [test](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test) и [testing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing).

Предлагаю убрать связь для меток [test](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test) и [testing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing) (или лучше синонимизировать эти метки с [тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)), т.к. Тестирование может быть: интеграционным, модульным, системным, приемочным, функциональным и др.

> [тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) в настоящее время нет утверждённых синонимов.

---

Если обратиться к enSO, то там существуют [следующие синонимы](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unit-testing/synonyms) для метки [unit-test]:

> The following tags will be remapped to [unit-testing]: 
>   [unit-test], [unit-tests] and [unittest]

Для метки [testing] определены [следующие синонимы](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/testing/synonyms):

> The following tags will be remapped to [testing]: 
>   [software-testing], [tests] and [test]

Comment: У нас в основном вопросы на юнит-тест и тех не особо много: 80 [вопросов на интеграционные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) и 400 [на юнит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing). Но в целом - идея неплохая.

Answer (score 3):

В "предлагаю" вы все правильно пишете, но в первом абзаце у вас какое-то противоречие:

> Следующие метки заменяются на юнит-тесты:
>
> unit-testing, unittest, модульные-тесты, test и testing.

[test](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test) и [testing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing) нельзя просто взять и заменить на [юнит-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b), поскольку они являются надмножеством, о чем вы справедливо пишете дальше:

> Тестирование может быть: интеграционным, модульным, системным,
>   приемочным, функциональным и др.

Comment: Это цитата из страницы [синонимы метки юнит-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B/synonyms)

Comment: @Anamnian аа, ну тогда это неправильно, конечно.